# adding Enhanced Link Attribution into 2017-12 Analytics code

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I want Enhanced Link Attribution. I downloaded a Google Analytics code snippet in December, 2017. Although the Analytics code has changed, I assume https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-link-attribution (as accessed 2017-12-10) still applies. It says to add a line of code, but now that the Analytics code has changed, where to add a line within the Analytics code is no longer clear. The three threads found in a search on Stack Overflow date from 2015 or earlier, so they're about old code (a newer list displayed while preparing this thread was also not applicable). So, on my newest website, I added the line just before the last script end tag. Was that an acceptable location for the line? If the line is no longer needed, is it at least harmless or do I have to go through pages to remove it?

Comment: see https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/enhanced-link-attribution

Comment: Okay, but do you know where to insert the new code? Or does it matter? Do I just put it before the second script end tag or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

As per the dev documentation, add it to the config command
eg:

```
<!-- Global Site Tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=GA_TRACKING_ID"></script>
<script>
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());

gtag('config', 'GA_TRACKING_ID', {
'link_attribution': true
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed before the final script end tag: https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Google-Analytics-Code/enhanced-link-attribution-code-placement-within-Analytics-code/m-p/1607861#M11439

Comment: Please avoid posting link-only answers. Instead, try to explain as much as possible in your answer and use link only as an additional reference.

Comment: That's what I did. There wasn't more that needed to be said (this forum prefers concision) and the link gave the authority for what I wrote for anyone who wished to verify it.

Comment: It's better to be a bit less concise in a case like this because we (the folks who are reviewing answers from the review queue) don't get to see everything in context but instead only see isolated answers and answers that contain mostly a link typically get flagged and deleted. I now see that it would be a "false positive" in your case but it's better to avoid formatting your answers in a way that it looks to a reviewer like an answer that needs to be deleted.

Comment: I personally don't like flagging cases like these, precisely because I know that it could, potentially, be a valid answer. And that's why I posted a comment instead of just flagging your answer. But I'm probably an exception rather than the rule. Flagging is much faster.